# Showing interstitial ad on every x loads of viewdidload

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, admob, uikit

I am trying to figure out, to show an interstitial ad on every x loads of viewdidload calls.
I am loading that ad, when my viewdidload calls. But I want to load it, when the viewdidload called x time.
Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code;

```
    class DetailController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    //Admob
    ...
    ...
    var fullScreenAds : GADInterstitial!

    //Interstitial-Ad
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial? {
        fullScreenAds = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: myInterstitialID)
        guard let fullScreenAds = fullScreenAds else {
            return nil
        }
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
        fullScreenAds.load(request)
        fullScreenAds.delegate = self

        return fullScreenAds
    }

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("Ads loaded.")
        ad.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }

    func interstitialDidFail(toPresentScreen ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("Ads not loaded.")
    }

    //MARK: View functions
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ......

        SVProgressHUD.show()
        imageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: pic.largeImageURL!)!, placeholderImage: imgPlaceHolder, filter: nil, progress: nil, progressQueue: DispatchQueue.main, imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.2), runImageTransitionIfCached: true) { (data) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }

        scrollView.delegate = self
        setupScrollView()
        setupGestureRecognizers()
        setupBanner()

        self.fullScreenAds = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
}
```

Comment: You could store a count using UserDefaults, then check if it has reached the limit, show your ad and reset the count

Comment: @sashatheitguy Are You mean "After Every X viewcontroller load"?

Comment: @LadumorDineshkumar yes.

Comment: I did not use UserDefaults before. If there is an example. It will help me.. @Scriptable

Comment: @sashatheitguy check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) to store a count each time the view is loaded. Once it reaches it's limit, reset the count and show the ad.

Example code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let adFrequency = 5
    private let userDefaults: UserDefaults = .standard
    private let defaultsKey = "passwordScreenViewCount"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let count = userDefaults.integer(forKey: defaultsKey)
        if count + 1 >= adFrequency {
            userDefaults.set(0, forKey: defaultsKey)
            // show the ad
        } else {
            userDefaults.set(count + 1, forKey: defaultsKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take 1 global variable `viewDidLoadCount` and set to 0.

Suppose you want to show ad every 5 `viewDidLoad()`. So,

Increment `viewDidLoadCount` by 1 in every `viewDidLoad()` method and check

//take global variable

```
var viewDidLoadCount : Int = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewDidLoadCount+=1
    if viewDidLoadCount == 5 {
        //send post notification to your main viewcontroller in which you have done code of ad delegate.
    }
}
```